# What is the reason for requiring &mut foo instead of &foo when foo has been declared mutable?

Tags: syntax, rust, ffi

For a C routine like

```c
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_Comm comm, int *rank);
```

The Rust foreign function interface could be declared like this:

```rust
use libc::c_int; // 0.2.79

#[link(name = "mpi")]
extern "C" {
    fn MPI_Comm_rank(mpi_comm: c_int, rank: *mut c_int);
}
```

I call the binding like this, which works, but left me puzzled about syntax:

```rust
pub static MPI_COMM_WORLD: libc::c_int = 0x44000000;
fn main() {
    let mut rank: c_int = 999999;
    /* but why '&mut rank' and not simply '&rank' ? */
    unsafe { MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &mut rank) }
}
```

I originally tried

```
unsafe { MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank) }
```

but this gives a compiler error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:12:44
   |
12 |     unsafe { MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank) }
   |                                            ^^^^^ types differ in mutability
   |
   = note: expected raw pointer `*mut i32`
                found reference `&i32`
```

I declared 'rank' as mut, so what gives?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You’re conflating two completely distinct features.

`let mut x;` makes a mutable binding `x`, allowing you to modify what x is bound to (`x = 42`) and for non-reference types to modify its contents (`x.y = 42`). It does not control the mutability of the *target* of references.

This is different from the type of references you’re dealing with.

- `&mut T` is a mutable reference and can be coerced to `*mut T`.
- `&T` is an immutable reference can be coerced to `*const T`.

As the function you are calling wants `*mut T`, you must pass it a `*mut T` or a `&mut T`; `*const T` or `&T` will not do.

To be sure, you can only take a mutable reference to mutable data, so `let x = 42; &mut x` doesn’t work as it needs `let mut x` instead of `let x`, but that’s still entirely distinct and is a part of Rust’s rules about mutability.

Answer (score 1):

Your function expects `*mut c_int` pointer (a mutable raw pointer), and you need to use `&mut` operator to obtain it. However, you can only take `&mut` pointer to `mut` variables, hence you need to declare `rank` variable as `mut rank`.

If your function expected `*const c_int` pointer, you would be able to use `&`, but this is not the case.